# How to run the django project in public ip address?

Tags: django

i have to run my django project in public ip address, i try to run my project in public ip address but it showing this error : Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

From above command you can access your Django app from `LAN` but it still won't be accessible from outside the LAN,

Comment: i want to acces my project from public ip address

Comment: i done it , i run the project from  which the service provider give ip address